# Trying to read from database table, but output is incorrect

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Here is my code:

**tracks.cshtml**

```
@page
@using Project.Models
@model Project.Pages.TracksModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<div class="row">
    <h1 class="display-2">Tracks</h1>
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
                <th>Artist name</th>
                <th>Album name</th>
                <th>Track ID</th>
                <th>Track name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach (Track track in Model.Tracks)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelArtists => track.Artist.Name)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelAlbums => track.Album.Title)</td>
                    <td>@track.TrackId</td>
                    <td>@track.Name</td>
                    <td><a asp-page="/Tracks/Details" asp-route-id="@track.TrackId">Details</a></td>
                    <td><a asp-page="/Tracks/Edit" asp-route-id="@track.TrackId">Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a asp-page="/Tracks/Delete" asp-route-id="@track.TrackId">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <p>Enter a name & TrackID (over 3510) for a new track:&nbsp;</p>
    <form method="POST">
        <div><input asp-for="Track.Name" /></div>
        <div><input asp-for="Track.TrackId" /></div>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
</div>
```

**tracks.cshtml.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Project.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Project.Pages
{
    public class TracksModel : PageModel
    {
        private Chinook db;

        public TracksModel(Chinook injectedContext)
        {
            db = injectedContext;
        }
        public IEnumerable<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
        public void OnGetAsync()
        {
            ViewData["Title"] = "Chinook Web Site - Tracks";
            Tracks = db.Tracks.Include(a => a.Album)
            .Include(a => a.Artist);
        }
        [BindProperty]
        public Track Track { get; set; }

        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Tracks.Add(Track);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToPage("/tracks");
            }
            return Page();
        }

        public IActionResult DeleteTrack(int TrackId)
        {
            var track = db.Tracks.Find(TrackId);

            if (track == null) return Page();

            db.Tracks.Remove(track); db.SaveChanges(); return RedirectToPage("/tracks");
        }
    }
}
```

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/double-happ1ness/chinook)

There is something wrong as the page appears to repeat the artist names multiple times, to such an extent that all the artists names that are displayed begin with the letter A. I should say that the way I have the database set up, `ArtistId` is a foreign key of the `Album` table, while `AlbumId` is a foreign key of the `Tracks` table.

Maybe I need clauses like `.Where(a => a.AlbumId == Tracks.AlbumId)` and `.Where(a => a.ArtistId == Album.ArtistId)`? I tried to write something like that, but I must have done it wrong as it just stopped the tracks from displaying altogether. Any help please? TIA

Edit: I'm noticing that whereas my Album titles are joined from the `Album` table, my Artist names are not, even though the method is essentially just the same. It occurs to me that whereas the `Album` table is directly connected to the `Track` table (through the `AlbumId` foreign key), the `Artist` table is not. It is only indirectly related to the 'Track' table, through the `Album` table`.

`Artist`----`Album`----`Track`

Edit2: I was told that `Where` is not needed in this instance, and that I should use 'ThenInclude`, so I've currently got

```
   public void OnGetAsync()
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = "Chinook Web Site - Tracks";
        Tracks = db.Tracks.Include(a => a.Album).ThenInclude(b => b.Artist).ToList();
    }
```

It's still resulting in the exact same error though.

Comment: Maybe you could provide the static html result for checking what's wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you mean. But if you look at this screenshot, perhaps you can see that there are far too many releases apparently by AC/DC. https://i.imgur.com/fYMZXFL.jpg That is not correct. The artist name is incorrectly repeated somehow.

Comment: Have you verified that the foreign key is correct in the DB? Because it looks like Aerosmith is coming across as ACDC also. Or have you debugged it and verified that its coming across correctly before hitting the loop?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure what you mean? I can get the artist names to display fine on other pages in my site, it's just this one page where I'm having this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point is at `Context.Chinook.cs`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            ....

            modelBuilder.Entity<Track>()
            .ToTable("tracks")
            .HasOne(mtype => mtype.Artist)
            .WithMany(trk => trk.Tracks)
            .HasForeignKey(mtype => mtype.AlbumId)
            .HasForeignKey(mtype => mtype.GenreId)
            .HasForeignKey(mtype => mtype.MediaTypeId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
        }
```

HasForeignKey chains must to be separated if they are not related to above relation(1 to n, n to 1, 1 to 1).
The followings are that codes I have modified.

Context.Chinook.cs

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Album>()
            .ToTable("albums")
                    .HasOne(al => al.Artist)
                .WithMany(ar => ar.Albums)
                .HasForeignKey(al => al.ArtistId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Artist>().ToTable("artists");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Media_type>()
            .ToTable("media_types")
            .HasKey(c => c.MediaTypeId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Genre>().ToTable("genres");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Track>()
            .ToTable("tracks")
            .HasOne(trk => trk.Album)
            .WithMany(trk => trk.Tracks)
            .HasForeignKey(trk => trk.AlbumId)
             .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Track>()
            .ToTable("tracks")
            .HasOne(trk => trk.Genre)
            .WithMany(trk => trk.Tracks)
            .HasForeignKey(trk => trk.GenreId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Track>()
            .ToTable("tracks")
            .HasOne(trk => trk.Media_type)
            .WithMany(trk => trk.Tracks)
           .HasForeignKey(mtype => mtype.MediaTypeId);
        }
```

Entities.Artist

```
public class Artist
{
     public int ArtistId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public ICollection<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}
```

Entities.Genre

```
public class Genre
{
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
}
```

Entities.Media_type

```
public class Media_type
{
    public  int MediaTypeId { get; set; }
    public  string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
}
```

Entities.Track

```
    public class Track
    {
        public int TrackId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? AlbumId { get; set; }
        public int? MediaTypeId { get; set; }
        public int? GenreId { get; set; }
        public string Composer { get; set; }
        public int? Milliseconds { get; set; }
        public int? Bytes { get; set; }
        public int? UnitPrice { get; set; }

        public Album Album { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public Media_type Media_type { get; set;}
    }
```

WebApp.tracks.cshtml.cs

```
   public void OnGetAsync()
   {
        ViewData["Title"] = "Chinook Web Site - Tracks";

        Tracks = db.Tracks
        .Include(a => a.Album)
        .ThenInclude(a => a.Artist);
   }
```

WebApp.tracks.cshtml

```
   <tbody>
                @foreach (Track track in Model.Tracks)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelArtists => track.Album.Artist.Name)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelAlbums => track.Album.Title)</td>
                        <td>@track.TrackId</td>
                        <td>@track.Name</td>
                        <td><a asp-page="/Tracks/Details" asp-route-id="@track.TrackId">Details</a></td>
                        <td><a asp-page="/Tracks/Edit" asp-route-id="@track.TrackId">Edit</a></td>
                        <td><a asp-page="/Tracks/Delete" asp-route-id="@track.TrackId">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                }
</tbody>
```

Reference:
[Entity Framework Core Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)